# ui-grid column alignment is disturbed when I set the minWidth

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am dynamically loading data into my ui-grid, so I do not know the number of columns beforehand. My ui-grid is working properly as long as I do not set the minWidth of the column, but as soon as I set the minWidth, the alignment is disturbed. Data from the rows above is being displayed on the rows below. But when I scroll to the right, the data automatically aligns itself.
I have attached images as this is kind of confusing. I have searched a lot, but could not get an answer anywhere.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of ui-grid you are using (your styling looks different).
If you are on the current version, you should be able to use the auto-resize option http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/213_auto_resizing which will resize the grid when data is first loaded. It will also resize when you resize the browser.

Comment: I'm using the latest version. I added the ui-grid-auto-resize directive, but it does not seem to work.